# The data couldn\U2019t be read because it isn\U2019t in the correct format using Af networking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i'm hitting  data this format...

```
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [DEFAULTS valueForKey:kUserIDKey],@"user_id",
                            @"0",@"page",
                            @"0",@"lastpage_id",
                            @"0",@"connection_id",nil];

    NSString *path  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kUserSamePageKey];

    [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[ApiHttpRequest sharedInstance] executeRequestWithHeaderPostParam:params forpath:path onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *response) {

        NSLog(@"response %@", response);

}];
```

please help me..

Thanks And Advice.

Comment: try NSASCIIStringEncoding

Comment: same coding yester day working..